# In SQL how do I write a query with CASE and COUNT

Tags: sql

I have this table with user email and company Id. A user can add more than one company to their account. So it is possible that a user can have more than one company Id to his email.
I want to write a query to count the users (this query I already written) and identify them as multiple companies users.
So in my COUNT statement how should I write to say that if there is more than one company id to that email identify as multi-company user.

Below is the query I have written to get the list of emails with more than one Id.

```
SELECT email, COUNT(company_id) AS count_of_companies 
FROM database
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(company_id) > 1
ORDER BY count_of_companies DEC;
```

Thank you

Comment: what is your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to identify and get the list of users as multi-company or not, I have modified your query

```
 SELECT EmailID, CASE  WHEN count_of_companies >  1  THEN 'MultiCompany User' ELSE 'Single' END FROM
   (
         SELECT EmailID, COUNT(companyID) AS count_of_companies 
          FROM #temp_company
          GROUP BY EmailID
   )t
```

Answer (score 0):

Count the company and partition by email:

```
select email,
 (case when count(companyid)over(partition by email) > 1
  then 'multi-company-user'
else 'single-company-user'
end) as count_of_companies
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SELECT EMAIL
        ,CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(COMPANY_ID) > 1
                THEN 'MULTI-COMPANY'
            ELSE 'SINGLE-COMPANY'
            END AS COUNT_OF_COMPANIES
        FROM DATABASEA 
        GROUP BY EMAIL
        ORDER BY COUNT_OF_COMPANIES DESC
```